# Proving conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I would like to prove the following three statements;

[image]

The first one I already solved:

$P(x,y|z) = \frac{P(x,y,z)}{P(z)} = \frac{P(y|x,z)P(x|z)}{P(z)} = \frac{P(y|x,z)P(x|z)P(z)}{P(z)} = P(x|z)P(y|x,z)$

However, with the second and third I struggle. The third one seems very intuitive and logic for me, but the academic proof is always a hard thing.

Could someone point me in the right direction for b and c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you proved (a), you can prove (c) as follows:

\begin{align*}
P(e_1,e_2\mid h)=P(e_2\mid h)\times P(e_1\mid e_2,h)=P(e_2\mid h)\times P(e_1\mid h)\end{align*}

where the first equality is (a) (with $e_2$ in place of $x$, $e_1$ in place of $y$ and $h$ in place of $z$) and the second is the given assumption in (c).

To start (b), you have by the law of total probability (or your intuition) that

$$P(x\mid z)=\sum_y P(x,y\mid z)$$

Can you take it from here (of course, using (a))?

Comment: (c) makes complete sense, just didn't know it was actually so straightforward to write it down. thank you! (b) I completely understand why this is equivalent, but even looking at my proof for (a) I fail to come up with the next step.

Comment: @DamiaanReijnaers Just plug in (a) for the term inside the summation: $P(x,y\mid z)=P(x\mid z)\times P(y\mid x,z)$ by (a) (where $x$ and $y$ have just changed roles). Do you see it now?